# Access Entity Framework autogenerated FK column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have  two classes, where `Plan` has a list of `PlanTask`, like below. However when it was initially made, there was not made a Property for the Foreign Key to go from `PlanTask` to `Plan`. However now i need the ID of `Plan` on `PlanTask`. My problem lies in because of the on to many relationship that exists between these two, Entity Framework created a Foreign Key column. However as i have no property to access that column, i can't access the id. So my question is, can i access the autogenerated column somehow, or can i edit my classes so that i don't delete the data that already exists.

Plan:

```
public class Plan
{
    public int PlanId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Navn")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<PlanTask> Tasks { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
    public PlanStages Stage { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ApprovedDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Ejer")]
    public User Owner { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Ejer e-mail")]
    public string OwnerMail { get; set; }
}
```

PlanTask:

```
public class PlanTask
{
    public int PlanTaskId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Beskrivelse/Årsag")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Indtast venligst en beskrivelse/årsag")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Løsning")]
    public string Solution { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Ansvarlig e-Mail")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Indtast venligst den ansvarliges mail")]
    public string ManagerMail { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Ansvarlig navn")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Indtast venligst den ansvarliges navn")]
    public string ManagerName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Videresend til navn")]
    public string ForwardName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Videresend til e-Mail")]
    public string ForwardMail { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Dato udført")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? DateCompleted { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Deadline for udførelse")]
    public DateTime? Deadline { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Dato der er fulgt op")]
    public DateTime? FollowupDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Påmindelses dato")]
    public DateTime? ReminderDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Vedhæft fil")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

DataContext:

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DataContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("AspNetRoles");


        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });


        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Departments)
            .WithMany(c => c.Users);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Users)
            .WithMany(c => c.Departments);


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


    }

    public static DataContext Create()
    {
        return new DataContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Section> Sections { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubmittedSheet> SubmittedSheets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubmittedQuestion> SubmittedQuestions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> WorkRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Actionplan> Plans { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ActionPlanTask> PlanTasks { get; set; }


    //public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is the relationship between `Plan` and `PlanTask` defined in the ModelBuilder? Because I see no `[ForeignKey]` decorations in your model. If so, please show this definition of the relationship!

Comment: It is not no. The relationship is seen in `Plan` that has a collection of `PlanTask` `public IList<PlanTask> Tasks { get; set; }`

Comment: Updated with Context class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or can i edit my classes so that i don't delete the data that already exists.

Yes. Just add

```
public Plan Plan {get; set; }

[Column("Plan_PlanId")]
[ForeignKey("Plan")]
public int PlanId { get; set; }
```

and make sure it exactly matches the name of the generated column. You can use attributes for that.

Test it with a little care but when you do it right and then do an add-migration that new migration should be empty.

Comment: Unfortunatly i have tried this, my mistake for not writing that. But i can see in the migration that it still drops the current table and names it the same with a 1 after

Comment: Sorry, the column. OnModelCreating does not apply the relationship, therefore i have not added it, however i can ofcourse do that.

Comment: The column name is Plan_PlanId. However i am unsure on how to mark it as a FK property properly, as if i make a int property and mark it with the ForeignKey attribute, i get an error. As i understand it i need a Plan property, and then an int property for the FK, is that correct?

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work, had forgotten about the Column attribute.